# Saving GUI as .jpg in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, jpeg, figure, save-as

In matlab, I have created a GUI with several plots and edit boxes filled with text for an experiment with the bike. These plots and edit box values vary depending on the data I input (120 different sets). I was able to save the GUI as a figure with

```
    saveas(handles.speedbike,fullfile(savename), 'fig');
```

Speedbike is the handle I gave to one of the plots and savename is the name that the figure is saved under, which changes with each set.
Now I also wish to save all the sepparate GUI's as jpegs, but using the same code as above, but with 'jpg' instead of 'fig' only saves a small corner of the figure as a jpeg, not the whole GUI.

Is there any function that I can use to correctly save a gui as a jpeg, or any way to open a .fig file, and then saving a copy of that as a jpeg.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the handle of the whole figure for your GUI, instead of the handle of one of the plots. You probably also want to use [`print`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html) for saving to jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found satisfactory results with this:

```
hg=get(0,'Children');
saveas(hg,'.\gui.fig','fig');
optsave.Format='png';
hgexport(hg,'.\gui.png',optsave);
```

Why this do not work?. This normally do with normal figures, and failed with GUI's:

```
optsave.Format='meta';
hgexport(hg,'.\gui.wmf',optsave);
```